# Ubuntu 16.10 akwardly slow at booting up after kali linux and Windows 10 triple boot

Tags: ubuntu, windows, kali-linux, dual-boot, bootable

I had Ubuntu 16.10 and Windows (ubuntu's grub as bootloader) on my laptop, yesterday I decided to install Kali with it too, so I shrank the Windows 10 partition of 60 gb and filled the created space with kali, I installed kali's version of grub.

The problem is that Ubuntu's booting screen (the purple screen with the ubuntu sign and the 5 dots) was pretty slow. At one point it passed from the normal purple coloration to a darker purple, and it took like *5 minutes to boot!*

After that I issued the command `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`.

I rebooted and now I had ubuntu's grub (the result I wanted to achieve), **but**, the problem was **not** fixed!

How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like you're [not the only one](/questions/239522/very-slow-boot-after-installing-kali-linux-along-with-ubuntu-windows).  Someone over at AskUbuntu had [the same problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/737319/ubuntu-is-booting-very-slowly-after-dual-boot-with-kali) — maybe the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/737340) there will help?

Comment: (A summary of the AskUbuntu page:) At least at some point in the past, Kali would change the UUID of the swap partition.  Then Ubuntu would have errors, slowing down the boot.  Check your `fstab` entries in both Ubuntu and Kali, and make sure they all point to valid partitions

Comment: @Fox damn, hope I can fix this without reinstalling.

Comment: @Fox Through the installation of kali it told me it would format sda6 (my ubuntu swap partition) as swap, but I thought it was ok and that ubuntu would keep using that partition along with kali.

Comment: @Fox Hey look can you be a bit more specific on fstab? I don't know what that means.

Comment: You shouldn't have to reinstall. Kali should have correct entries since you just installed it. Which partition is your swap? Find its UUID (with `blkid`) then make sure Ubuntu's `/etc/fstab` points to the right UUID

Comment: @Fox Yep, Ubuntu's was not correct! I found out without using blkid but using it blkid reveals the same thing.

Comment: @Fox I'm updating kali, when it finishes I'll boot into Ubuntu and let you know

Comment: @Fox the boot time got better, but not as good as before everything happened, and the screen becoming darker is still happening

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54846/discussion-between-fox-and-tommaso-thea-cioni).

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I fixed this on my laptop.

Background: Brand new Asus Gaming laptop with i7 and 16GB RAM. Has a Samsung 960 NVME. Would boot Win10 to the desktop in 4 seconds from power on.

Installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.3 and was taking over a minute to boot with Grub timeout set to 1 second and Windows as primary (used grub customizer).

Tried turning off fast boot and turned off superfetch service.

How I fixed it:
In the bios, the boot order had Ubuntu listed first, Windows second. I changed it to Windows first, that fixed it.

The side effect is now I have to hit ESC to bring up boot order if I want to boot Ubnuntu. I'll also have to use grub customizer again to set Ubuntu as primary.